# How to dynamically call a method in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a method:

```
  add(int x,int y)
```

I also have:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 6;
string s = "add";
```

Is it possible to call `add(a,b)` using the string `s`?

Comment: `if (s == "add") { add(a,b); }` This?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

> how can i do this in c#?

Using reflection.

`add` has to be a member of some type, so (cutting out a lot of detail):

```
typeof(MyType).GetMethod("add").Invoke(null, new [] {arg1, arg2})
```

This assumes `add` is static (otherwise first argument to `Invoke` is the object) and I don't need extra parameters to uniquely identify the method in the `GetMethod` call.

Comment: @DavidStratton It will work with `private` members: use one of the overloads of [`GetMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05eey4y9.aspx) that takes a [`BindingFlags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) argument with `BindingFlags.NonPublic`.

Comment: Can we use "Func<>" instead of Refection ?

Comment: @Sreekumar No, because to create a lambda you either need to fix at compile time or build expression trees. The latter done dynamically will need to use reflection.

Answer (score 26):

Use reflection - try the `Type.GetMethod` Method

Something like

```
MethodInfo addMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod("add");
object result = addMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { x, y } );
```

You lose strong typing and compile-time checking - invoke doesn't know how many parameters the method expects, and what their types are and what the actual type of the return value is. So things could fail at runtime if you don't get it right.

It's also slower.

Comment: any idea how can I make this call as await

Comment: Only problem I had was `this` was `null`

Answer (score 17):

If the functions are known at compile time and you just want to avoid writing a switch statement.

Setup:

```
Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, int>> functions =
  new Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, int>>();

functions["add"] = this.add;
functions["subtract"] = this.subtract;
```

Called by:

```
string functionName = "add";
int x = 1;
int y = 2;

int z = functions[functionName](x, y);
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use reflection.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            Type t = p.GetType();
            MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("add", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            string result = mi.Invoke(p, new object[] {4, 5}).ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("Result = " + result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private int add(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Richard's answer is great. Just to expand it a bit:

This can be useful in a situation where you dynamically created an object of unknown type and need to call its method:

```
var do = xs.Deserialize(new XmlTextReader(ms)); // example - XML deserialization
do.GetType().GetMethod("myMethodName").Invoke(do, new [] {arg1, arg2});
```

becasue at compile time `do` is just an `Object`.

Comment: How can I make this method awaitable?

Comment: What issue are you facing, please elaborate.

Comment: I wanted to call this method asynchronously. I found solution. I type casted it as task like this.   `await (Task)do.GetType().GetMethod("myMethodName").Invoke(do, new [] {arg1, arg2});`