# Dynamically calling method and class name

Tags: c#, .net, class

I have some cases where I have to call method names from class names.

```
string scenario1 = "MockScenario1";
string scenario2 = "MockScenario2";

MockScenario1.GetInfo();
MockScenario2.GetInfo();
```

How can I dynamically use the strings to call method name here like

```
scenario1.GetInfo()
scenario2.GetInfo()
```

I tried to find out all options by string and control space to find related options. Any suggestions?

I am tried the below and trying to Get class name generated dynamically

The below code generated method name dynamically

```
string methodName = "hello";

//Get the method information using the method info class
 MethodInfo mi = this.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);

//Invoke the method
// (null- no parameter for the method call
// or you can pass the array of parameters...)
mi.Invoke(this, null);
```

More clear scenario:
I am trying to send class name as parameter
MockScenario1 and MockScenario2 are class names.

```
string scenarioCats = "MockScenario1";
string scenarioDogs = "MockScenario2";
GetResult(scenarioCats);
GetResult(scenarioDogs);

public static void GetCatsResult(string scenarioCats){
scenarioCats obj = new scenarioCats();
    obj.GetInfo();    
}
public static void GetDogsResult(string scenarioDogs){
scenarioDogs obj = new scenarioDogs();
    obj.GetInfo();    
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [string to variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293549/string-to-variable-name)

Comment: Check the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044455/c-sharp-reflection-how-to-get-class-reference-from-string

Comment: Look into http://stackoverflow.com/a/39793450/5962841 it shows an example of getting a method from a class

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? What's the real goal?

Comment: I will edit with goal.

Comment: just like MethodInfo do we have something like class info to manage class name dynamically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to dynamically call a function in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254817/how-to-dynamically-call-a-function-in-c-sharp)

Comment: you could do the reverse, i.e. declare classes normally and use the (quite) new C# `nameof` keyword to declare your strings.

Comment: See my answer bellow

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How to create an instance of a type from its string representation:

```
string scenario1 = "TheNamespace.MockScenario1";
Type theType = this.GetType().Assembly.GetType(scenario1);
var theInstance = (MockScenario1)Activator.CreateInstance(theType);
theInstance.GetInfo();
```

It will be better if your classes implement a common interface, for example *IGetInfoAware*, and then you could write a more generic loader:

```
var theInstance = (IGetInfoAware)Activator.CreateInstance(theType);
```

**Note:** you need to provide the full class name for scenario1 and scenario2

See [Activator.CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx)

**EDIT:**

As @Georg pointed out, if the type is not declared in the assembly of the context objects, then it is necessary first to get the assembly where the type is hosted:

```
var theAssembly = (
    from Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    where (assembly.FullName == "TheNamespace.AssemblyName")
    select assembly
)
.FirstOrDefault();

if ( theAssembly!= null ){
    Type theType = theAssembly.GetType(scenario1);
    var theInstance = (IGetInfoAware)Activator.CreateInstance(theType);
    theInstance.GetInfo();
}
```

If for some reason the assembly name is unknown to you, then the type could be resolved like the following:

```
public Type GetTypeFromString(String typeName)
{
    foreach (Assembly theAssembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    {
        Type theType = theAssembly.GetType(typeName);
        if (theType != null)
        {
            return theType;                    
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I think that the assumption that the type is located in the assembly of the context objects type is a design flaw. If someone inherits the class in a different assembly, this already changes the behavior, even if nothing else is changed. You should better let the client chose the assembly in which you want to search the type or you can expect an assembly-qualified type name.

Comment: @Georg, that is a good observation, I have updated the answer to deal with the scenario you pointed out.

Answer (score 5):

You can use reflection:

```
Type thisType = this.GetType();
MethodInfo theMethod =      thisType.GetMethod(FunctionName);
theMethod.Invoke(this, userParameters);
```

Comment: Its the type name which is given as string, not the function name.

Comment: You should enter type name if not invoking the method on the current class

Comment: my intension is to pass mockscenario1,2,3 etc as parameters. With above code I have to give classname implicity and it is tightly bound.

Comment: If you want to pass classname as string the best answer is what @E-BAT have wrote

Comment: This is what I Was looking for in GOogle so +1

Answer (score 5):

You could use the command design pattern. So you'd use a hash map to store your string as the key in the hash map, and then your function would be the value of the hashmap. Then when you want to call your function you say hashmap.get ("yourString"). This would return the function that you stored as your value and you could call it from there.

Comment: Welcome to [so], tip: adding code is always a good idea... see all the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using `Dictionary<String, Action>`, where you can put down all the scenarios and their names e.g.

```
private static Dictionary<String, Action> s_Scenario = 
  new Dictionary<String, Action>() {
    {"MockScenario1", () => MockScenario1.GetInfo()},
    {"MockScenario2", () => MockScenario2.GetInfo()}, 
  }; 

...

s_Scenario["MockScenario1"]();  
s_Scenario["MockScenario2"]();
```

Comment: You can also add with `{"MockScenario1", MockScenario1.GetInfo },` directly. Note: no parentheses after `GetInfo`!

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes: you're quite right `MockScenario1.GetInfo` is a terser solution; I just tried to show that *any labda* (not necessary a single method) can be used as a valid scenario, e.g. `{"MockScenarios1and2", () => {MockScenario1.GetInfo(); MockScenario2.GetInfo(); }  }`

Comment: my intension is to pass mockscenario1,2,3 etc as parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Without giving `Namespace` to `GetType()` can return null always (I faced with that problem before adding this answer.), so it should be like this;

As you mentioned, you want to give string as parameter

```
public void GetCatsResult(string scenarioCats)
        {
            string item = this.GetType().Namespace + "." + scenarioCats; 
            // combined class string with the namespace
            Type className = Type.GetType(item);
            // found the class
            MethodInfo m = className.GetMethod("GetInfo");
            // get the method from class
            object value = m.Invoke(null,null);
            // invoke and value will represent the return value.
        }
```

Here is my Scenario class,

```
class Scenario1
    {
        public static string GetInfo()
        {
            return "GetInfo() called, Scenario1";
        }
    }
```

**Result;** (btw `GetCatsResult()` called at `Form_Load` and given string which declared as `string scenario1 = "Scenario1";`)

[image]

Hope helps,

Answer (score 0):

If it is for testing you can use PrivateObject:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        PrivateObject myClassPrivateObject = new PrivateObject(myClass, new PrivateType(typeof(MyClass)));

        myClassPrivateObject.Invoke("MyMethod");
    }
}
```