# Is it possible to dynamically RegisterType in Unity using a string class name?

Tags: c#, unity-container

In Unity is it possible to Register a type if I only know the string name of the concrete type?

For example rather than doing something like this:

```
IUnityContainer container = ...
container.RegisterType<IMyInterface<MyType>, MyConcreteType>(...));
```

I want to do something like this:

```
IUnityContainer container = ...
container.RegisterType<IMyInterface<MyType>, "className">(...));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40242977/dynamically-calling-method-and-class-name

Comment: Yeah I've tried doing something like that but Unity complains saying the Type is used like a variable.